# Conflicting javascript with mail chimp

Tags: javascript, jquery, mailchimp

I've just added a subscription form from mailchimp to my page and my existing java functions have stopped working. Obviously there are two conflicting sources. Here's the original:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

and the mail chimp source:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='//s3.amazonaws.com/downloads.mailchimp.com/js/mc-validate.js'></script>
```

What can I do to have the two work in tandem?

Comment: You are missing the two sources.

Comment: @BenM No, they were there, but indented improperly.

Comment: Try using namespaces maybe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/881515/how-do-i-declare-a-namespace-in-javascript (Basically creating an object and then calling everything from there)

Comment: What is conflicting? I see jquery.min.js & mc-validate.js, which don't appear to conflict in any "obvious" manner...

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan mc-validate includes jQuery v1.9

Answer (score 0):

```
<script src="other_lib.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script>
$.noConflict();
// Code that uses other library's $ can follow here.
</script>
```

https://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/